# Text processing using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the sample file, I would like to check if "field5" exists in file, if exists check if 67890 exits, if exists then print corresponding values for "field5"

sample output:

```
112
```

---

```
START
field1
field2
field3
field4
field5
field6
END

12345|5|1|2|3|4|111|555
67890|5|6|7|8|9|112|000
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some python code in your question. If you have some, even if wrong, please [edit] the question to include it

Answer (score 1):

Finding content in file you can achieve by looping over its lines like so:

```
def process_text():
    f = open('filename.txt')
    for line in f:
        if 'field5' in line:
            break
    else: return
    f.seek(0) # get back to the begining of the file (if you want to)
    for line in f:
        if '67890' in line:
            numbers = line.split(sep='|') # getting the list that contains the numbers
    else: return

    print(numbers[-1]) # print the last element
```

**NOTE:** This is python3.5.2. In python 2.7 split method should look like this: `line.split('|')` (without keywords).

Comment: Hi,

I forgot to mention, if this a position based on above? if we have field6.

Comment: Position of what, 67890 or the numbers after?

Comment: Hi,

Lets say field5 exists, then  112 is the value corresponding to field5 when you line starting with 67890 in the first column. 
67890|5|6|7|8|9|112|000

Comment: Then you have to change the last line to `print(numbers[1+5])`, because `print(numbers[-1])` means that you're gonna print the last number.